# reduce ytick density for two pgfplots in groupplot

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

please help me adjust the ytick density of my second plot in the groupplot I have shown. I have tried to increase the max space as suggested from another thread but it only works for the first plot and not the second one. I tried positioning in a different area i.e. after addplot, but that didn't work either. Thanks for your time.

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = .72, transform shape,trim left]    
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
rows=1,
columns=2,
horizontal sep=0pt,
},
    scale only axis,
    xlabel={nm},
    ylabel={Abs},
    xmin=385, xmax=565, 
    xtick pos=left,
    ytick pos=left,
    no marks,
    max space between ticks=50pt
]
 \nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(a)} $50:25$ (CoPor:\Lig{1}),max space between ticks=50pt]
 \addplot  table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=30] {ST051 5025 Me-IMD SG.csv}; 
 \addplot  table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=600] {ST051 5025 Me-IMD SG.csv}; 


\nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(b)} $50:25$ (CoPor:Buffer),ylabel ={}]
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=30] {ST051 5025 blank SG.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=600] {ST051 5025 blank SG.csv};

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Abs. spectra of $50:25$ CoPor:\Lig{1} and CoPor:Buffer (served as a blank) after 30 \si{\minute} and 600 \si{\minute} showing gradual thermodynamic change of complex. Buffer was 100 \si{\milli\molar} \ce{NaH2PO4}.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Since you didn't provide a working example, I'll give you my guess. According to the [PGFPLOTS Manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf), page 293, you should use integer numbers for `max space between ticks=` and remove the `pt` suffix. Also set it once inside the options for `\begin{groupplot}[ ]`. You may increase the value `50` to get the correct output.

Comment: did my working example not show? I have uploaded the example with a photo, is it not viewable? ... I tried your suggestion and the second plot still does not have the effect.

Comment: ,@SpencerTrinh People here cannot reproduce your figures, they don't have that `ST051 5025 Me-IMD SG.csv` thing, e.g. That's why I say "you didn't provide a working example".

Comment: ok its clear. i thought it wasn't necessary for the raw data. thanks for your help anyways.